# Virtual interface on virtual machine on OpenStack

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, replication, load-balancing, openstack

I’ve 4 virtual machines, with Debian 7 S.O., created over openstack.

The first one is a Web Server, the second one and the third one are 2 db with multi-master replica (MySQL) and the last one is a loadbalancer configured with ldirectord.

On the loadbalancer I’ve a phisical interface (eth0) and a virtual interface (eth0:0).
On each of the database I’ve a lo:0 with the same ip of the virtual interface created over the loadbalancer. From each db I can ping the virtual interface of the loadbalancer without problem, but when I try to ping that virtual interface from the web server I’ve this result:

PING 172.29.12.13 (172.29.12.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.29.12.4 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

and if I try to connect to MySQL (with the load balancer) it doesn’t work!

If I try to send ARP -n command from the webserver, I can't get mac address of the virtual interface of the loadbalancer (eth0:0)

I’ve the same configuration with 4 virtual machines on my desktop created with VMWare and I haven’t any problem!

There’re some difference between VMWare and OpenStack?

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my English

This is the /etc/network/interfaces of the loadbalancer

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The normal eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address         172.29.12.5
        netmask         255.255.255.0
        broadcast       172.29.12.255
        network         172.29.12.0
        gateway         172.29.12.1

# Maybe the VM has 2 NICs?
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

# Maybe the VM has 3 NICs?
allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp

# Virtual Interface for ldirectord
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
        address         172.29.12.13
        netmask         255.255.255.0
        broadcast       172.29.12.255
```

This is the /etc/network/interfaces of the db

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The normal eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address         172.29.12.11
        netmask         255.255.255.0
        broadcast       172.29.12.255
        gateway         172.29.12.1

# Maybe the VM has 2 NICs?
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

# Maybe the VM has 3 NICs?
allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp

# Virtual interface for loadbalancer
auto lo:0
iface lo:0 inet static
        address 172.29.12.13
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        pre-up sysctl -p > /dev/null
        post-up route add -host 172.29.12.13 dev lo:0
```